# Save a sequence of JsObject into JSON file

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am using Play Framework to convert a case class to JSON object. This for many instances of case class LinkEvolution. Given the structure of each JSON object :

```
    implicit val linkIPFormat = Json.format[LinkIPs]
    implicit val linkState = Json.format[LinkState]

    // user has JsObject as type
    val linkEvolution = LinkEvolution(rawDataLink.link, reference, current, alarms)

    val user = Json.obj(
                  "link" -> rawDataLink.link,
                  "reference" -> linkEvolution.reference,
                  "current" -> linkEvolution.current,
                  "alarms" -> linkEvolution.alarms)
```

I have a list of users, so a list of JsObject.
My question is how I can save this list in a JSON file, each line of the file is a JsObject.

Comment: encode the json as string and save it to a file like how you save a normal text file, just write a method to save and load the file

Answer (score 0):

You can conevrt them to strings and write to a file (I assumed users=List[JsObject]):

```
import java.io._

val file = "file.json"
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
users.map(_.toString).{ json =>
   writer.write(json)
   writer.newLine
}
writer.close()
```